# Wordpress - Restrict access to plugin only

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin using Wordpress and I would like to create a user account that ONLY has access to this plugin.

In other words when the user logs in to the wordpress admin panel this plugin is the only thing they see.

Comment: Do you need the user to have access only to the functionality provided by your plugin? If so, what is this functionality and how will the user access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the menu of the plugin available to the user level's capability. As you can [see in WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus),

`add_options_page('My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options');`

'manage_options' is a capability of an administrator. A subscriber's capability is 'read', so replace 'manage_options' with 'read' and you'll give access to the subscriber.

This not only works with add_option_page, but also with add_menu_page, add_plugins_page, etc.

Here's a complete list of [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Comment: Interesting. Wondering how I can give a user access to a certain plugin only. A subscriber has access to his own profile so perhaps I just need to add read to the plugin in question (SimpleMap) for access. Perhaps I can do this in a theme's functions.php ?

Comment: If i change the capability to read, then the user can see all other plugins under that category. I was hoping to write some code for that particular user to see only that plugin or create a new role for only that plugin.

Comment: Just to answer my own comment above, i used the capability plugin to to create roles and in my plugin code used the same role.