# How to Restrict access to plugin only in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions

I want to restrict user to access only specific plugin(or one plugin only).
I have tried plugins but not working as per requirement. I have checked this question [Wordpress - Restrict access to plugin only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453196/wordpress-restrict-access-to-plugin-only) but not working because want to provide all access of specific plugin

How can i do it using code?

Answer (score 0):

there is in fact a plugin for giving user roles access to different parts of the admin, a plugin I use is https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

You can hide/show pretty much the whole thing.

Hope this helps!